# How to make without exception uppercase and lowercase letters in tcl regsub?

Tags: tcl, youtube-dl, regsub

I want to regsub without exception, so as not to double I do a regsub.

example before:
`regsub -all "feat" $songtitle "" songtitle`
`regsub -all "Feat" $songtitle "" songtitle`

I want a simple one line for regsub:
`regsub -all "feat" $songtitle "" songtitle`

It's a little inconvenient if there are many words that I want to regsub, I want it to be simple with no exceptions in the regsub, so that only one line of each word is regsub, not two lines for uppercase and lowercase letters. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `-nocase` option to `regsub` to get it to ignore case when matching.

```
regsub -all -nocase {feat} $songtitle "" songtitle
```

You can also enable that mode of operation by putting the `(?i)` marker at the start of the RE:

```
regsub -all {(?i)feat} $songtitle "" songtitle
```

You probably should put some `\y` (a word boundary constraint) in that RE too, so that it doesn't change `defeated` into `deed`:

```
regsub -all {(?i)\yfeat\y} $songtitle "" songtitle
```

(Once you add either backslashes or square brackets to an RE, it's pretty much essential in Tcl that you put the RE in curly braces. Otherwise you end up using a disgustingly large number of backslashes…)

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware of the `string map` command:

```
string map {feat "" Feat ""} $songtitle
```

Useful when you don't actually need regular expressions.